# Удалить фрагмент или активити из истории

Tags: android, java

У меня есть активити, где пользователь логинится. После того, как пользователь вошел в систему, ему открывается другое (основное) активити. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии "Назад" из основного активити, ничего не происходило?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно переопределить метод [onBackPressed](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html), но это будет по крайней мере странно в том смысле, что пользователь нажимая назад ожидает переход на предыдущее окно или закрытие приложения.

Comment: По-моему, логично, что вошедший в систему пользователь не может открыть страницу "Вход в систему". Разве нет? :( Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - хранить собственную очередь и при запуске каждой Activity проверять что мы собственно запускаем и переключать куда нужно.
А вообще вот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001882/how-to-clear-specific-activity-from-the-stack-history/5002392#5002392

Answer (score 0):

после того как залогинились и вызвали интент основной активити, для активити где польователь логинится нужно вызвать метод finish(). Если работаете с фрагментами то нужно при нажатии на HardBack в главном фрагменте вызывать дополнительно метод popBackStack

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще в манифесте для активити авторизации указать параметр noHistory:

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity" android:noHistory="true" />
```